# How can I detect overwritten css properties?

Tags: javascript, css, firebug, stylesheet, google-chrome-devtools

I can get all css properties for an element with document.stylesheets but some of those are not active because those properties are overwritten. In firebug (chrome developer tools also has this feature), if there's an overwritten css property, you will see something like that:
[image]

The only way I can think of is comparing active css property for the element (in jQuery `$(element).css(property)`) and defined css property in `document.stylesheets` but it's not a reliable way to do it. Any suggestion?

Comment: The browser has to know, because it calculates the specificity of the selectors to determine the final outcome. All the Dev Tools are doing is keeping track of those calculations and showing you them. To do the same in JS, you'd have to construct an entire CSS parser...

Comment: @Kolink, thanks. it seems there's no way to track browser's calculations without any extension, right?

Comment: I may be missing something but I can see in DevTools that overwritten properties are crossed over in the same way as they are in firebug (http://imgur.com/W9liZs8). So, what's the issue here?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Is there an underlying problem that this may solve?  (if so, maybe we can help with other solutions to THAT problem.)

Comment: @andi this can be useful for website builders, and apps like that.

Answer (score 8):

In webkit, you can use `getMatchedCSSRules` to achieve what you want. It returns a CSS Rule set in order of inheritance applied by the browser and it [is what the webkit inspector used](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79653) some time ago. For Gecko based browsers like Firefox there seems to be a polyfill available [here](https://gist.github.com/ydaniv/3033012) although I've not tested it.

### A basic, working solution

[**The following code is also available as a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UXJHt/)

Because `getMatchedCSSRules` [only works with inline stylesheets](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69626), you will first have to inline your linked stylesheets:

```
function inlineStyles() {
    var stylesheets = document.getElementsByTagName('link'),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < stylesheets.length; i++) {
        if (stylesheets[i].getAttribute('rel') == 'stylesheet') {
            (function (stylesheet) {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", stylesheet.getAttribute('href'), true);
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        var inlineStyle = document.createElement('style');
                        inlineStyle.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
                        inlineStyle.innerText = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        head.replaceChild(inlineStyle, stylesheet);
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.send();
            })(stylesheets[i]);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    };
}
```

Then, the big chunk: This is a first shot, improve at will. It can handle `inherit` rules and up to one `!important` definition, but that's it. For really complicated setups, this will have to be improved:

```
function getStyle(s, id) {
    var element = typeof id === 'string' ? document.getElementById(id) : id,
        css = window.getMatchedCSSRules(element),
        style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
        value = style[s],
        styles = [],
        rules = [],
        inherited, currentRule;

    // if there's a computed style, start calculation
    if (value) {

        // add matched rules if there are any
        if (css) {
            for (var i = 0; i < css.length; i++) {
                styles.push(css[i]);
            }
        }

        // add the element style attribute as a matched rule
        styles.push({
            style: element.style,
            cssText: 'element.style {' + element.getAttribute('style') + ' }'
        });

        for (var i = styles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var def = styles[i],
                rule = {
                    index: rules.length,
                    style: s,
                    value: styles[i].style[s],
                    cssText: def.cssText
                };

            if (rule.value == 'inherit' && !currentRule) {
                if (inherited = getInherited(element, s, value)) {
                    rule.inheritedFrom = inherited;
                    currentRule = rule;
                    inherited = undefined;
                } else {
                    rules.push(rule);
                }
            } else if (rule.value == 'inherit' && currentRule && isImportant(s, value, def.cssText)) {
                if (inherited = getInherited(element, s, def)) {
                    rule.inheritedFrom = inherited;
                    rules.splice(currentRule.index, 0, currentRule);
                    currentRule = rule;
                    inherited = undefined;
                } else {
                    rules.push(rule);
                }
            } else if (rule.value == value && !currentRule) {
                currentRule = rule;
            } else if (rule.value == value && currentRule && isImportant(s, value, def.cssText)) {
                rules.splice(currentRule.index, 0, currentRule);
                currentRule = rule;
            } else if (rule.value.length) {
                rules.push(rule)
            }
        }

        return {
            current: currentRule,
            overwritten: rules
        };

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If Inheritance is taking place, we walk up the DOM Nodes to find the element that defines the CSS Rule with this helper function and get its style:

```
function getInherited(element, s, value) {
    while (element.parentNode && window.getComputedStyle(element.parentNode)[s] == value) {
        element = element.parentNode;
    }

    if (element) {
        return getStyle(s, element).current;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

We determine if a CSS Rule is marked as important with this helper function:

```
function isImportant(s, style, text) {
    return new RegExp(s.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-$1').toLowerCase() + ':\\s+' + style + '\\s+!important').test(text)
}
```

[**Have a look at the fiddle to see it working**](http://jsfiddle.net/UXJHt/)

Comment: I'm having trouble with the input on the demo. It says please use `POST` request. Can you tell me what to put in the input so I can see it working.

Comment: @Connor use `result` as Element ID and `font-size` as CSS property, these are the ones I defined in the CSS & HTML of the fiddle, if you want any other you can define them in the fiddle directly and query for them.

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fontSize' of null` what browser are you using?

Comment: Any webkit browser will do: Chrome, Chromium or Safari. See the first sentence, there's a polyfill for Gecko based Browsers but it is not used in this solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using chrome. but `getMatchedCSSRules` is what I was looking for anyway :)

Comment: `getMatchedCSSRules` is now deprecated. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/blink-dev/fd-QLCiLESQ/discussion

Comment: This will not always work, if the external css contains relative path (ie bg image urls), they will be relative to the css domain and inlining them will break those paths

Answer (score 2):

This snippet may be useful to you, its helped me in the past, apply it in one of your CSS files, and you will be able to see what objects are being overridden by other class / id rules by finding the specific places where elements CSS declarations are, and by tracking their parents. My guess is you're having issues with inheritance.

```
* { outline: 2px dotted red }
* * { outline: 2px dotted green }
* * * { outline: 2px dotted orange }
* * * * { outline: 2px dotted blue }
* * * * * { outline: 1px solid red }
* * * * * * { outline: 1px solid green }
* * * * * * * { outline: 1px solid orange }
* * * * * * * * { outline: 1px solid blue }
```

Alternatively you could add a :hover attribute to those, and it would make it a bit easier to navigate, but the basic principal of the snippet is to show you the nesting of elements, and may help you to determine where the issues in your CSS are

Comment: Actually I'm trying to do something like firebug or chrome developer tools. thanks though. :)

Comment: I had assumed you were already using the tools, considering you included an image ;)

Comment: @Xenology yes, the image is to explain what he want's to achieve, so let's just assume he wants to rebuild devTools, so OP would need to figure out how to detect over-ridden styles

Comment: As of my knowledge there is no way to detect over ridden styles. Its generally just good practice to know when and where your styles may be conflicting. The only other option I could see would be to manually determine the weight of any CSS selector with JS and then build an object based off that. This would be much mroe of an issue in a totally different realm than CSS or JS. Detecting over ridden styles is something the browser does as the CSS rendering level. Thus recreating it in CSS and JS would be incredibly difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to parse the CSS files that are linked to the page to be able to determine the styles that are being used. You would also have to determine what properties can be used to target elements in CSS. Here is the flow you would have to follow:

**Elements can be targets by:** tags, IDs, classes, pseudo classes and inheritance

You would then have a given element, for instance:

`<a href="#" id="link" class="button">Woop</a>`

That element has several selectors associated to it by default. All elements can inherit parent CSS, so you would have to create a hierarchy of parent elements. Later styles will take precedence. You then have to take into account the tag `a` and any parent that also shares this selector such as `body a`. Likewise, you would have to create a hierarchy of inherited attributes. You would repeat this process for classes, attributes, and pseudo-classes. Once you have compiled your list of trees for the element, you can then parse the CSS documents for the appropriate styles.

This is definitely a huge undertaking and there is no sense in reinventing the wheel. What I would suggest is looking at open source projects that have already done this. [WebKit](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit) is an open-source project that has already built this system. Consider using their implementation as a starting point and make your changes from there.

Comment: This is not a practical solution though since you can't parse CSS that is referenced from different origin.

Comment: You can if you use something like easyXDM.

Comment: You don't need easyXDM in the first place if there is CORS. And if there is no CORS, then you cannot access the CSS without using a proxy server (which cannot then access intranet and cookies which the whole point of same origin policy). easyXDM is just tying different APIs together, it doesn't give you something that wasn't already physically possible.

Comment: You're right, even firebug doesn't support this. I wonder if you could use a hosted proxy with a JSONP callback?

Comment: You can use [yahoo YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) but it's not perfect (if css is cookie-based or hosted on cross-intranet it doesn't work)

Comment: It will be a wonderful day when XDR is supported everywhere :)